How to decode & save encoded file?
I'm trying to extract a file and can't figure out how to translate & save the file. It's from phrack http://www.phrack.org/issues/70/5.html#article
Near the bottom is:
--[ 9 - Source Code

begin 644 vm_escape.tar.gz
...  #<== Save and decode this
end


|=[ EOF ]=---------------------------------------------------------------=|

I tried opening vim and copy pasting the result, and then opening it with archive viewer but that didn't work. I think it might be base 64 encoded but I can't tell for certain. If anyone can try and save & extract the file that would be good.

I found the solution was the kind of encoding used was this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding I saved the file from begin 644 to end inclusive of begin and end as vm_escape.uuencoded
sudo apt-get install sharutils
uudecode vm_escape.uuencoded
The result is the file vm_escape.tar.gz
